# dmake not found when installing Perl module using CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan, dmake

I installed Perl from ActiveState. Plain version with no extensions. Windows 10.
    "This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 1 (v5.28.1) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread"

A pre-existing perl script that I need to use accesses PostScript::Simple so I need to add that to my install.

Supposedly, the right way to do this is to open cpan and run the command "install PostScript::Simple".

However, it eventually fails with a dmake error. I've tried cpan install dmake and appears to be trying to do so, but that also fails.

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading 'H:\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 25 Sep 2019 15:55:37 GMT
Running install for module 'PostScript::Simple'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.01)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.074)
Checksum for H:\.cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MC\MCNEWTON\PostScript-Simple-0.09.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.30)
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20181129_28)
Configuring M/MC/MCNEWTON/PostScript-Simple-0.09.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a dmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for PostScript::Simple
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  MCNEWTON/PostScript-Simple-0.09.tar.gz
  C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for M/MC/MCNEWTON/PostScript-Simple-0.09.tar.gz
**'dmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,**
operable program or batch file.
  MCNEWTON/PostScript-Simple-0.09.tar.gz
  dmake -- NOT OK
```

Comment: Since posting this question, I also went into cpan and did an "install YAML" (noted as not installed during the PostScript::Simple install attempt). Along the way, it also ran into dmake issues (same error).

Comment: @stevieb - I have mingw installed on my system and tried pointing cpan to its make exe:  

`cpan[2]> o conf make c:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe
    make               [c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe]
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!`  

After:  
`cpan[4]> o conf make
    make               [c:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe]
Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items`  

However, installing PostScript::Simple still failed as it didn't seem to like the mingw make exe.

Answer (score 2):

Run`cpan`, and execute the following:

```
o conf make
```

Here's an example from one of my Windows systems:

```
cpan> o conf make
    make               [C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe]
```

Check to see if the file listed in the make option is available on your system where `cpan` thinks it is (the entry may just be missing the path information to the binary).

If it's not, either find it, or look for another make program (`gmake.exe` is common), then enter the path and the make program's filename with the configuration command under `cpan`:

```
cpan> o conf make C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin\\gmake.exe
    make               [C:\Strawb~1\c\bin\gmake.exe]
    commit: wrote 'C:\Strawberry\perl\lib/CPAN/Config.pm'
```

Comment: The question is about ActivePerl, not Strawberry.

Comment: @daxim Whether it be ActivePerl or Strawberry, would the troubleshooting steps not be the same?